# Push Notifications on iPhone without alerts to the user

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

I have searched the web on my question but did not find anyone answering it. This looks weird as I am sure other people face similar issue.

At the moment my app is receiving push notification fine. I have a chat module where user can speak and whenever a new message is being sent, the other phone receive a push notification to update the chat.

You could say no issue there, but the problem is when the user is out of the application: he is still receiving those notifications showing a banner on the screen, and I want to dis-activate this. Basically I want push notification without alerts to the user. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just leave the **sound property** of your push notification payload **empty**, **omit the alert/text property** and add **`"content-available":1`** and your notification will be **silent**. This is often referred to as silent push notification or "push-to-sync".

See [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html):

> For a push notification to trigger a download operation, the
>   notification’s payload must include the content-available key with its
>   value set to 1. When that key is present, the system wakes the app in
>   the background (or launches it into the background) and calls the app
>   delegate’s
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
>   method. Your implementation of that method should download the
>   relevant content and integrate it into your app

So your payload should least look like this:

```
    {
        "aps" : {
            "content-available" : 1,
            "sound" : ""
        },
        "chat-message" : "Hello World!"
    }
```

Comment: thanks this work, the following website is a good source too: http://hayageek.com/ios-silent-push-notifications/